# Cygnus dosen't forward the data to HDFS

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

After configuring Cygnus in my filab vm, I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR - es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:140‌​)] Persistence error (The default_org/XYZ directory could not be created in HDFS. HttpFS response: 400 Bad Request)
```

A concrete example will this one:

```
(SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:140)] Persistence error (The default_org/<XX:YY:ZZ:AA:BB>-<entity-type> directory could not be created in HDFS. HttpFS response: 400 Bad Request)
```

I am following the next manual to run cygnus:
https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/tree/develop/flume but the problem persist.

My cygnus.conf is the next one:

```
#=============================================
# To be put in APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/cygnus.conf
#
# General configuration template explaining how to setup a sink of each of the available types (HDFS, CKAN, MySQL).

#=============================================
# The next tree fields set the sources, sinks and channels used by Cygnus. You could use different names than the
# ones suggested below, but in that case make sure you keep coherence in properties names along the configuration file.
# Regarding sinks, you can use multiple types at the same time; the only requirement is to provide a channel for each
# one of them (this example shows how to configure 3 sink types at the same time). Even, you can define more than one
# sink of the same type and sharing the channel in order to improve the performance (this is like having
# multi-threading).
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = hdfs-sink
cygnusagent.channels = hdfs-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = hdfs-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded 
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Management interface port (temporal location for this parameter)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.management_port = 8081
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts de
# Interceptor type, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# Destination extractor interceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.de.type = es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.interceptors.DestinationExtractor$Builder
# Matching table for the destination extractor interceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.de.matching_table = /usr/cygnus/conf/matching_table.conf

# ============================================
# OrionHDFSSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = hdfs-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink
# Comma-separated list of FQDN/IP address regarding the Cosmos Namenode endpoints
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_host = cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org
# port of the Cosmos service listening for persistence operations; 14000 for httpfs, 50070 for webhdfs and free choice for inifinty
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_port = 14000
# default username allowed to write in HDFS
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_default_username = <fiware_user>
# default password for the default username
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_default_password = <fiware_password>
# HDFS backend type (webhdfs, httpfs or infinity)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_api = httpfs
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.attr_persistence = column
# Hive FQDN/IP address of the Hive server
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_host = <fiware_user>@cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org 
# Hive port for Hive external table provisioning
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_port = 10000

#=============================================
# hdfs-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Comment: Could you provide the Cygnus configuration, please? Which is the entity id and type you are trying to persist?

Comment: Done. Now you can see my config.

I'm sorry but via this site I can't share with you the names and types of the entities :(

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the delay. Some additional questions that usually lead to an answer: Dis you installed from sources or by using the RPM? Is your VM placed at the spanish node or is it placed into other one node?